# Computer RAM not running at expected frequency unless I force an overclock

Tags: memory

I set up a Desktop with the following components:

- **Processor**: Ryzen 5 3600X
- **GPU**: AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT
- **MB**: Asus Tuf Gaming B550M-Plus
- **RAM**: Corsair Vengeance 3200Mhz (2x8GB Dual-Channel)

When I first turned on the computer, the RAM was running at 2133Mhz each. My motherboard specification says it can run RAM at 3200Mhz without overclocking. So, why do I need to use D.O.C.P. (Direct Over Clock Profile) to get my RAM running at their full speed (3200MHz)? Shouldn't it be just plug and go? Why do I need to overclock them to get it running at the expected speed?

The reason I am asking about this, is because I discovered that the D.O.C.P. (Direct Over Clock Profile) mode was causing screen flickering and crashes on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

RAM starts at baseline speeds so as to work 'out of the box'.  Your motherboard has a RAM speed spec, and so does your CPU.  CPU's can run RAM at various speeds based upon the kind of chips and how much RAM you install.  You should reference your CPU's manual to determine the best speed to run your 16GB of dual-channel RAM (in 2 sticks.)  I suspect it is less than 3200Mhz.  For my system, I was able to choose the 2nd XMP profile in the RAM, then bump down the clock speed to make it stable.  There are many guides on getting the best stable speed out of your RAM and it can get quite complicated.  But you are typically only fighting for a 1-2% speed gain for your overall system.

Comment: So, I am gonna have to configured it manually until it stabilize? I can't find the Ryzen 5 3600x manual on the internet, not even at the official AMD support page for it. Do you know where I can find it to get more details? On the specifications, it says this CPU can run RAM up to 3200Mhz.

Comment: So I was remembering my Mobo Manual which has very good details on Ryzen processor capabilities [Asrock X570M Pro4](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/X570M%20Pro4.pdf)  It says your Matisse processor can do 3200 with 2 dual rank chips.  On that Asrock board it recommends installing them in the A2 and B2 slots, but that may or may not hold true for your Asus board.  Your chips should not be adjacent, they should be in the 1 and 3 slots or the 2 and 4 slots.  Does your memory have any other XMP profiles to load?

Comment: Hey Brian, I already look for that information when I was first installing the memories at the computer. For my Mobo, they need to be in A2 and B2 slots, already done that.

Comment: Awkwardly, I've done some adjustments at the FCLK Frequency and it seems to stabilized. I only set the FCLK from 1600Mhz to 1800Mhz. For what I read, it should be 1600Mhz, since the advertised clock speed of the memories is 3200Mhz, but somehow they appear to be stabilized with FCLK 1800Mhz. I used TestMem 5.0 to test it, and it was ok. Gonna use the machine normally for some days to see what happens.